# Eclipse in Linux doesn't see new package

Tags: linux, eclipse

In an existing Eclipse project, I created a new package (using Eclipse in Linux) and checked it into source control (we use Subversion).

Another user got the new files and can see them in Eclipse on Windows, but not in Linux. The new files are there, just not visible in Eclipse.

I was thinking it might be an Eclipse setting that only lets him see some file types - there are .feature and .java files - but there are pre-existing .java files that he does see in Eclipse.

Any clue what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you see the files in terminal ? I mean, try this: ls -a and please post the result here.

Comment: Where they checked out using SVN in Eclipse or externally to Eclipse? If it was done externally `File > Refresh` may be needed.

Comment: Yes, we see the files in the terminal. I don't have access to the user's machine, so can't post the results, sorry. Are there any hidden files we should be looking for?

Comment: They were checked out using svn outside of Eclipse. He also deleted and reimported the project in Eclipse. Would that accomplish the same thing as File > Refresh?

Comment: He also File > Refreshed for good measure. Still haven't figured this one out.